# C++ plotting libraries for visualizing the solution of TSP using Genetic Algorithms

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm, code-visualization

I'm building a project to solve TSP using genetic algorithms in C++. I'm looking for C++ plotting libraries that I can use to visualize the solution. I found a video on youtube & was wondering if something like this can be done in  C++. Video link : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC5CX8drAtU](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC5CX8drAtU)

Link to the github repo of my project:  https://github.com/hello-fri-end/Parallel-Implementation-of-Genetic-Algorithms-for-TSP

Comment: I doubt if many people will want to watch a video for you. Please could you summarize the main points, perhaps with an image?

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are:

1. [GDI+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-gdi-start) - if you want to develop for Windows
2. [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) - if you want a cross-platform solution